# MPI gathering c++ vectors induced conditional jump or move depending on uninitialised values

Tags: c++, mpi, valgrind, openmpi

I am trying to write a C++ code using MPI (version: OpenMPI/4.0.1-GCC-8.3.0-2.32), in which I will gather some std::vectors as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <mpi.h>

int main() {
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    int num = 10;
    std::vector<double>     yield;

    yield.resize(num, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < yield.size(); i++) yield[i] = i;

    std::vector<double> totyield;
    if (0 == world_rank) totyield.resize(num * world_size, 0);
    MPI_Gather(yield.data(), yield.size(), MPI_DOUBLE, totyield.data(), yield.size(), MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (0 == world_rank) {
        for (int i = 0; i < yield.size(); i++) std::cout << yield[i] << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < totyield.size(); i++) std::cout << totyield[i] << std::endl;
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

The code seems OK. Because when I run it, it will print correct results.

But when I run the code with valgrind (version: valgrind/3.15.0-openmpi):

```
mpirun --mca btl_openib_allow_ib 1 -np 2 valgrind --leak-check=yes --track-origins=yes ./vec1
```

I got many reports of "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)" as well as memory loss like "xx bytes in x blocks are definitely lost in loss record xx of xx". Because I am new to mpi, I am confused if this problem is created by me. More important, I am worried about **if this undefined behavior can create some segmentation fault in some rare cases.**

Some example of the conditional jump are as follows:

```
==267664== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==267664==    at 0x74898B2: btl_openib_handle_incoming (in /cvmfs/fgi.csc.fi/apps/el7/OpenMPI/4.0.1-GCC-8.3.0-2.32/lib/openmpi/mca_btl_openib.so)
==267664==    by 0x748B3FB: poll_device (in /cvmfs/fgi.csc.fi/apps/el7/OpenMPI/4.0.1-GCC-8.3.0-2.32/lib/openmpi/mca_btl_openib.so)
==267664==    by 0x748BDF2: btl_openib_component_progress (in /cvmfs/fgi.csc.fi/apps/el7/OpenMPI/4.0.1-GCC-8.3.0-2.32/lib/openmpi/mca_btl_openib.so)
==267664==    by 0x57C23FB: opal_progress (in /cvmfs/fgi.csc.fi/apps/el7/OpenMPI/4.0.1-GCC-8.3.0-2.32/lib/libopen-pal.so.40.20.1)
==267664==    by 0x87F78D4: mca_pml_ob1_recv (in /cvmfs/fgi.csc.fi/apps/el7/OpenMPI/4.0.1-GCC-8.3.0-2.32/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_ob1.so)
==267664==    by 0x40D41EE: ompi_coll_base_gather_intra_basic_linear (in /cvmfs/fgi.csc.fi/apps/el7/OpenMPI/4.0.1-GCC-8.3.0-2.32/lib/libmpi.so.40.20.1)
==267664==    by 0x409EFF0: PMPI_Gather (in /cvmfs/fgi.csc.fi/apps/el7/OpenMPI/4.0.1-GCC-8.3.0-2.32/lib/libmpi.so.40.20.1)
==267664==    by 0x401059: main (in path_to_my_file)
==267664==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==267664==    at 0x4C3F76A: memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:908)
==267664==    by 0x4C3F882: posix_memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:1072)
==267664==    by 0x5819156: mca_mpool_default_alloc (in /cvmfs/fgi.csc.fi/apps/el7/OpenMPI/4.0.1-GCC-8.3.0-2.32/lib/libopen-pal.so.40.20.1)
==267664==    by 0x57B97D0: opal_free_list_grow_st (in /cvmfs/fgi.csc.fi/apps/el7/OpenMPI/4.0.1-GCC-8.3.0-2.32/lib/libopen-pal.so.40.20.1)
==267664==    by 0x74816CE: prepare_device_for_use (in /cvmfs/fgi.csc.fi/apps/el7/OpenMPI/4.0.1-GCC-8.3.0-2.32/lib/openmpi/mca_btl_openib.so)
==267664==    by 0x7482741: mca_btl_openib_add_procs (in /cvmfs/fgi.csc.fi/apps/el7/OpenMPI/4.0.1-GCC-8.3.0-2.32/lib/openmpi/mca_btl_openib.so)
==267664==    by 0x74544EC: mca_bml_r2_add_procs (in /cvmfs/fgi.csc.fi/apps/el7/OpenMPI/4.0.1-GCC-8.3.0-2.32/lib/openmpi/mca_bml_r2.so)
==267664==    by 0x87F3473: mca_pml_ob1_add_procs (in /cvmfs/fgi.csc.fi/apps/el7/OpenMPI/4.0.1-GCC-8.3.0-2.32/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_ob1.so)
==267664==    by 0x407A456: ompi_mpi_init (in /cvmfs/fgi.csc.fi/apps/el7/OpenMPI/4.0.1-GCC-8.3.0-2.32/lib/libmpi.so.40.20.1)
==267664==    by 0x40A50B0: PMPI_Init (in /cvmfs/fgi.csc.fi/apps/el7/OpenMPI/4.0.1-GCC-8.3.0-2.32/lib/libmpi.so.40.20.1)
==267664==    by 0x400E85: main (in path_to_my_file)

==267664== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==267664==    at 0x53513DC: __printf_fp_l (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==267664==    by 0x53504D6: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==267664==    by 0x537B178: vsnprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==267664==    by 0x4F50F8E: std::__convert_from_v(__locale_struct* const&, char*, int, char const*, ...) (c++locale.h:92)
==267664==    by 0x4F7D7D1: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_float<double>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, char, double) const (locale_facets.tcc:1005)
==267664==    by 0x4F8902B: put (locale_facets.h:2438)
==267664==    by 0x4F8902B: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<double>(double) (ostream.tcc:73)
==267664==    by 0x4011A5: main (in path_to_my_file)
==267664==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==267664==    at 0x4C3F76A: memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:908)
==267664==    by 0x4C3F882: posix_memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:1072)
==267664==    by 0x5819156: mca_mpool_default_alloc (in /cvmfs/fgi.csc.fi/apps/el7/OpenMPI/4.0.1-GCC-8.3.0-2.32/lib/libopen-pal.so.40.20.1)
==267664==    by 0x57B97D0: opal_free_list_grow_st (in /cvmfs/fgi.csc.fi/apps/el7/OpenMPI/4.0.1-GCC-8.3.0-2.32/lib/libopen-pal.so.40.20.1)
==267664==    by 0x74816CE: prepare_device_for_use (in /cvmfs/fgi.csc.fi/apps/el7/OpenMPI/4.0.1-GCC-8.3.0-2.32/lib/openmpi/mca_btl_openib.so)
==267664==    by 0x7482741: mca_btl_openib_add_procs (in /cvmfs/fgi.csc.fi/apps/el7/OpenMPI/4.0.1-GCC-8.3.0-2.32/lib/openmpi/mca_btl_openib.so)
==267664==    by 0x74544EC: mca_bml_r2_add_procs (in /cvmfs/fgi.csc.fi/apps/el7/OpenMPI/4.0.1-GCC-8.3.0-2.32/lib/openmpi/mca_bml_r2.so)
==267664==    by 0x87F3473: mca_pml_ob1_add_procs (in /cvmfs/fgi.csc.fi/apps/el7/OpenMPI/4.0.1-GCC-8.3.0-2.32/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_ob1.so)
==267664==    by 0x407A456: ompi_mpi_init (in /cvmfs/fgi.csc.fi/apps/el7/OpenMPI/4.0.1-GCC-8.3.0-2.32/lib/libmpi.so.40.20.1)
==267664==    by 0x40A50B0: PMPI_Init (in /cvmfs/fgi.csc.fi/apps/el7/OpenMPI/4.0.1-GCC-8.3.0-2.32/lib/libmpi.so.40.20.1)
==267664==    by 0x400E85: main (in path_to_my_file)
```

Comment: You are using `yield.size()` twice instead of `totyield.size()` in `MPI_GATHER`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I think I didn't make mistake at this part. Because the second ```int recv_count``` in ```MPI_Gather``` refers to the size of data coming from each processor.

Comment: @JINTLG you are right about the size parameter. I wonder if MPI is testing for the occurrence of `MPI_IN_PLACE`, and because you have not initialized the vectors, this is dangerous. I suggest that instead of resize you compute a size parameter `totalsize` which is zero almost everywhere, and then create the vector as `std::vector<double> totyield(totalsize)`.

Comment: (Let me note as an aside that the MPL library, which is a real C++ interface to MPI, has a polymorphic `MPI_Gather` where the sending processes do not have to specify a receive buffer.)

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Thank you. I initialized the ```totyield``` by this way ```std::vector<double> totyield(num * world_size, 0);``` instead of ```std::vector<double> totyield;```, but I still get the same report from valgrind.

Comment: Not every MPI implementation is completely valgrind-clean. That's all I can say.

Comment: If you look closely, the complains `valgrind` has originate in `libmpi.so.40.20.1`, and `ostream.tcc`. There isn't much you can do there except file a bug report against the library (after ensuring what you sent to the library conforms to the declarations and the parameters are initialized)